# $document->addScript('TEST'.JURI::root(true)

Tags: php, joomla2.5

i have a problem with `$document` in Joomla
This code: `$document->addScript('TEST'.JURI::root(true)` 
Give me: `/home/users/mdk-eu/public_html/TEST/` 
Why?

`JURI::root` and `JURI::base` are empty.

Answer (score 0):

`JURI::base(true)` return empty string in frontend and `/administrator` in backend 
[jdocs-JURI:BASE()](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/base) 
 
`JURI::root()` return `http://sitename.com` in frontend and backend as well. 
[jdocs-JURI:ROOT()](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/root)

What are you trying to achieve? 
You should use `JURI:root()` to get site url and add script to your site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to import a script, you should do it like so:

```
$document->addScript( JURI::root() . "path/to/file.js" );
```

`JURI::root()` defines the root of your Joomla site, so the path should be relative to that such as

```
$document->addScript( JURI::root() . "modules/mod_menu/assets/menu.js" );
```